# "Hi there!" -- What does this 'there' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

There's this particular interjection-like usage of ***there*** that I think belongs to the spoken register and maybe doesn't refer to anything; as in:

> - Hi ***there***!
> - You alright ***there***?

Why is it used, and what meaning (if any) does it serve to convey?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Hi there!* is a greeting. *There*  refers to the position that the other person is in, so it is an *adverb*. It can also serve to attract attention.

*Hi over there!* or *Hello over there* works the same way as *Hi there* or *Hello there*, except that the distance between the two people is greater. The two people could be across a room or across the globe.

I think you you are right about social register, as *Hi there!* seems to me to be informal or at least not formal.  This is also indicated by *Hi*.

The *there* in *You all right there* is also an adverb. You can also say things such as *Hey there!* and *You there!* and not say it in a friendly way. You can also say *Who goes there?*

Another stock phrase is

*There she goes!*

where, again, *there* is an adverb and is used to attract attention to whatever *she* is, be she a *female person*, a boat, or, in this case  just about anything.

Comment: I don't think *there* refers to the position that the other person is in the same way as the dummy there doesn't refer to any position as in "There is a book on the table." Only *on the table* refers to the position. If so, we might have to say "Hi here" to a person who is close. But "Hi there" is used to a person in any position. I think It is closer to an interjection in a more formal form than **yo** or **bro**. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

With respect to people here who still think that "**there**" in greetings doesn't refers to distance here is my explanation:

Firstly, educated people *(mostly native speakers)* say that before, when sailors wanted to draw the attention of someone at a distance *(to hail a ship or anything else at a distance)* they would shout, "**Ahoy, there**!" in which "**there**" refers to a distant object. Sometimes "there" was followed by the identity of the object: "**Ahoy, there, ship/captain/matey**".

Now we use "**hi**", "**hello**", "**greetings**", "**hey**" and etc. instead of "**ahoy**" but "**there**" is still used to emphasize the physical distance between the speaker and the object addressed.

Often "**there**" is used in place of the unidentified object when the object can't be visually identified at a large distance of because of fog, mist, or other visual obstacles.

> "**Hi/Hello/Greetings/Hey, There**" is not impolite or anyway rude, but mostly appears in informal usage.

**Footnote**: *"**there**" isn't the **dummy subject** in these greetings. "**There**" is a dummy subject mostly in constructions **there is** or **there are***, or before certain verbs in certain contexts.

Comment: Would you please provide a source for the maritime origin you noted?

Comment: @Færd I'll be glad to, but only tomorrow since I'm not at the PC now.

Answer (score 3):

'There' in such sentences is used to indicate direction or place where the person is and it is informal. It directs attention towards the person indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Some interesting responses here about "hi, there," although I would argue that in common usage, no matter its origins, it's mainly a cheery colloquialism.

On the other hand, if it helps, I'd most likely use a question like "Are you all right, there?" to address someone who seemed spaced out (distant in thought, in other words).